# How to Nest Proofs in a Useful Way

Tags: boxes, amsthm, thmtools, amsbook

I am using amsthm and amsbook and nesting claims and proofs. I would like to have two things:

1) Proofs that are in a deeper layer should be indented.

2) There should be a semi-box (only left and bottom lines) around each proof to help the reader. If the proof is longer than a page the left line of the box should continue over pages.

This is what my example looks like right now:
[image]
This is what my example *should* look like:[image]
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[oneside,english,reqno]{amsbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\claimname}{Claim}
\providecommand{\definitionname}{Definition}
\providecommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=\thm@preskip, 
  spacebelow=\thm@postskip,
  headfont=\normalfont\scshape,
  notefont=\mdseries, 
  notebraces={(}{)},
  numberwithin=section,
  headformat=\smash{\fbox{\NUMBER.}}~\NAME\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\BodyFont,
]{boxed}
\def\BodyFont{\normalfont\itshape}
\declaretheorem[style=boxed,name=\theoremname]{thm}
\declaretheorem[style=boxed,name=\claimname]{claim}
\def\BodyFont{\normalfont}
\declaretheorem[style=boxed,name=\definitionname]{defn}

\numberwithin{section}{chapter}

\makeatletter 
\let\sv@thm\@thm
\def\@thm{\let\indent\relax\sv@thm} 

\let\oldref\ref
\newcommand\thref[1]{\textup{\fbox{\ref{#1}}}}

\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\proof\endcsname
  {\normalparindent}{0pt }{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\section{First Section}

\begin{claim}
\label{claim:Cool_Claim}Some Claim some words some words some
words some words some words some words some words some words some
words some words some words some words some words some words some
words some words some words some words some words some words some
words some words some words some words
\begin{proof}
This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof.  This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof.
\end{proof}
\end{claim}
\begin{claim}
This is a new claim
\begin{proof}
This is the proof of the new claim. 
\begin{claim}
Here is a subclaim of the new claim.
\begin{proof}
And this is the proof of the subclaim.
\end{proof}
\end{claim}
\end{proof}
\end{claim}
\begin{defn}
Some Definition
\end{defn}
This is now normal text again. As we learnt in \thref{claim:Cool_Claim}. 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to achieve this using [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) and surrounding the `proof` environment with an appropriate `mdframed` environment:

```
\documentclass[oneside,english,reqno]{amsbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\surroundwithmdframed[
  hidealllines=true,
  leftline=true,
  bottomline=true,
  innertopmargin=0pt,
  skipabove=\dimexpr\topsep+6pt\relax,
  skipbelow=\topsep,
  innerrightmargin=0pt,
]{proof}

\makeatletter
\providecommand{\claimname}{Claim}
\providecommand{\definitionname}{Definition}
\providecommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=\thm@preskip, 
  spacebelow=\thm@postskip,
  headfont=\normalfont\scshape,
  notefont=\mdseries, 
  notebraces={(}{)},
  numberwithin=section,
  headformat=\smash{\fbox{\NUMBER.}}~\NAME\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\BodyFont,
]{boxed}
\def\BodyFont{\normalfont\itshape}
\declaretheorem[style=boxed,name=\theoremname]{thm}
\declaretheorem[style=boxed,name=\claimname]{claim}
\def\BodyFont{\normalfont}
\declaretheorem[style=boxed,name=\definitionname]{defn}

\numberwithin{section}{chapter}

\makeatletter 
\let\sv@thm\@thm
\def\@thm{\let\indent\relax\sv@thm} 

\let\oldref\ref
\newcommand\thref[1]{\textup{\fbox{\ref{#1}}}}

\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\proof\endcsname
  {\normalparindent}{0pt }{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\section{First Section}

\begin{claim}
\label{claim:Cool_Claim}Some Claim some words some words some
words some words some words some words some words some words some
words some words some words some words some words some words some
words some words some words some words some words some words some
words some words some words some words
\begin{proof}
This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof.  This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof. This is the text of the proof.
\end{proof}
\end{claim}
\begin{claim}
This is a new claim
\begin{proof}
This is the proof of the new claim. 
\begin{claim}
Here is a subclaim of the new claim.
\begin{proof}
And this is the proof of the subclaim.
\end{proof}
\end{claim}
\end{proof}
\end{claim}
\begin{defn}
Some Definition
\end{defn}
This is now normal text again. As we learnt in \thref{claim:Cool_Claim}. 
\end{document}
```

[image]

As **barbara beeton** has mentioned in a comment, having each structure with an independent counter will be a nightmare for your readers; it's much better to let the structures share one counter (achieved using the `sibling` key from `thmtools`). A little reduced example showing how to obtain structures sharing a counter:

```
\documentclass[oneside,english,reqno]{amsbook}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\numberwithin{section}{chapter}

\providecommand{\claimname}{Claim}
\providecommand{\definitionname}{Definition}
\providecommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=\thm@preskip, 
  spacebelow=\thm@postskip,
  headfont=\normalfont\scshape,
  notefont=\mdseries, 
  notebraces={(}{)},
  headformat=\smash{\fbox{\NUMBER.}}~\NAME\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\BodyFont,
]{boxed}
\def\BodyFont{\normalfont\itshape}
\declaretheorem[style=boxed,numberwithin=section,name=\theoremname]{thm}
\declaretheorem[style=boxed,name=\claimname,sibling=thm]{claim}
\def\BodyFont{\normalfont}
\declaretheorem[style=boxed,name=\definitionname,sibling=thm]{defn}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\begin{claim}
test
\end{claim}
\begin{claim}
test
\end{claim}
\begin{defn}
test
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

Comment: very nice!  i may steal it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. Feel free to steal it :) I also liked this idea (although it has so many lines, in my opinion). Since the rule is there to mark the end of a proof the end-mark could be suppressed.

Comment: i'll have to think about the final end-of-proof mark.  you're probably right. i suppose that some text could follow the sub-claim, and in that case, the mark should not be suppressed.  i do find the "matching" numbers for claims and definitions disconcerting -- did we learn something in claim 1.1.1 or definition 1.1.1?  there's something to be said for using just a single numbering for *everything* (probably secion-wise) to make it reasonable to find what's being referred to.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, the counter should be shared. However, there seems to be some incompatibility trying to achieve this with `thmtools`: I haven't tested the similar approach directly using `amsthm` (as in another answer from the same OP). Could we continue this discussion in a chat room? (I'll be around here in some hours).

Comment: If space allows, it may be prudent to indent a little from the right, too. Myself, I'd do away with the lines but add an indicator at the end-of-proof marker, e.g. like `$\square_{\text{1.3.1}}$`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton the problem I mentioned before was solved; I added to my answer a little remark about (and a simple example of) letting the structures to share a counter.